# Looping in JQuery is not doing what I want it to

Tags: jquery

I created a function so that when user hovers over an image, the image opacity lowers and the visibility of text becomes visible and not hidden. I used loops to apply this functionality for multiple classes, but the looping isn't doing what I want it to do. I am not sure why.

This is what I want it to do

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var classes = [".col0",".col1", ".col2", ".col3", ".col4", ".col5", ".col6", ".col7", ".col8"]

    $(classes[0]).hover(function(){
        $(classes[0]).css("opacity", "0.5");
        }, function(){
        $(classes[0]).css("opacity", "1");
    });
    $(classes[1]).hover(function(){
        $(classes[1]).css("opacity", "0.5");
        }, function(){
        $(classes[1]).css("opacity", "1");
    });
    ..... And continue until it finishes all the variables 
});
```

I tried using loops like this. The above solution works, but it is a lot of repetition so I want to use loop, but loop does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var classes = [".col0",".col1", ".col2", ".col3", ".col4", ".col5", ".col6", ".col7", ".col8"]

    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        $(classes[i]).hover(function(){
            $(classes[i]).css("opacity", "0.5");
            }, function(){
            $(classes[i]).css("opacity", "1");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding a common class to all of these elements if possible, instead of looping. @Geeky - The way he's changing CSS is completely legitimate, furthermore your syntax is wrong. Objects use `:`, not comma, nor is it necessary if you're only changing one property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know, jQuery accepts multiple elements as a selector, just as `$(".col1, .col2")` etc etc - so do that. Convert your array to a string list and go from there:

```
var classes = [".col0",".col1", ".col2", ".col3", ".col4", ".col5", ".col6", ".col7", ".col8"]
var selector = classes.join(",");

$(selector).hover(function(){
    $(this).css("opacity", "0.5");
}, function(){
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
});
```

Using an instance of `this` - you'll be able to get the current element being hovered and do what you need.

Comment: But what if I want to change the opacity of another div.   $(selector).hover(function(){
    $('m-0').css("opacity", "0.5");
}, function(){
    $('m-0').css("opacity", "1");
}); Assuming m-0 exist, and there is m-1, m-2, and so forth. How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var classes = [".col0",".col1", ".col2", ".col3", ".col4", ".col5", ".col6", ".col7", ".col8"]

    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        $(classes+[i]).hover(function(){
            $(this).css("opacity", "0.5");
            }, function(){
            $(this).css("opacity", "1");
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.col1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.col2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.col3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col1">
</div>
<div class="col2">
</div>
<div class="col3">
</div>
```